# How to specify a generic type that itself declares a generic type

Tags: java, generics

I have a class Range, the declaration of which reads:

```
public abstract class Range<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

I'd like to create a class RangeSet that takes one generic type -- a Range. In the body of the RangeSet class, however, I'd like to be able to refer to two generic types

1. The Range the RangeSet was typed with, and
2. The `T extends Comparable<T>` the Range was typed with

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think so?  What is your use case?  you may just be able to declare a variable of type Comparable...

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are getting at. Working on it now. Would you please add some additional information of the "what" you are trying to accomplish? This might help conjure a solution.

Comment: @IronMan84 Thank you IronMan, I try my hardest to be as liberal as possible with my accepts but I've found that for the majority of the few questions I've asked the answers I haven't received answers that are direct responses to my question -- often they simply state things I'm already aware of that are merely tangential to the issue at hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would have to make your `RangeSet` have two type parameters. For example:

```
public class RangeSet<T extends Comparable<T>, R extends Range<T>> {
    // ...
}
```

However, are you sure that you really need the type `R` of the `Range`? Couldn't you just make the methods in `RangeSet` accept a `Range<T>` instead of `R`?

Comment: Thanks, yes or no was what I was looking for, and I think you may be right that the type R is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

You can define

```
class RangeSet<T extends Comparable<T>, R extends Range<T>>
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm aware of this though would prefer a solution involving only one type